# Query Designer does not recognize quotation marks in the name of synonym (Oracle)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, ado.net, oracle11g, dataset

I need to get access to a synonym on a Oracle database.

What I have done so far is:

-Create a DataSet.

-Open the server explorer.

-Open the dataset designer and put the synonym (let's say it's name is "abc") in the dataset designer.

-Right click on 'add query' and then open the query designer.

The problem is when I try to write:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema."abc"
```

the system automatically delete the quotation marks so it will end in an Oracle's exception (ORA-00942) which tells me that the table or view does not exist.

There is no way I can rename the synonym.

Is there a way to turn off the autocorrection feature?

I can also get access through DataReader but I want to use the dataset designer.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Thx

Edit:

This problem does only appear when I am using Oracle provider.
I created a synonym with the same name in a MSSQL database and the system automatically recognize the synonym with quote marks.
It seems that it's a bug in the oracle provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotation mark around your table name also. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM "myschema"."abc"
```

It worked for me